# NGINX - Is it possible to specify custom locations if the root location is using proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx

I'm a server noob, so I might be wrong about what's happening here and how to solve it, but anyway. I have a node server running on port 3000 and served at the base of my domain.

```
server {
    server_name blahblah.com www.blahblah.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /test/ {
        index index.html
        root /var/www/html;
    }
    
    ...
```

I want to add a new static location (test) that should override the proxy_pass setup above, but I think the `/` block is consuming everything that comes after it because when I visit /test it takes me to my node app's custom 404 page. Is this something that's possible to make work?

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: What 404 page do you want to show, if not the one from your node app? Where did you define an `error_page`?

Comment: Did you reload nginx configuration after making the change? Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to show the 404 page for all routes apart from /test/ in this case.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I did, Nginx says all green

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to your question.

Comment: Notice, it is capital `-T`, not `-t`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the `location {}` order is only effective for ***regexp*** locations (`location ~ {}`). Normal (***prefix***) locations are matching using the [***longest match***](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) rule.